# Обновление страницы и клик в браузере в цикле

Tags: javascript

Имею проблему - на одном сайте ежедневно в 9 утра появляется ограниченное количество мест на оказание услуги. В это время на пару секунд становится активным поле выбора галочки, и нужно успеть нажать кнопку  Continue. Делать это я не успеваю увы. можно ли вставить какой скрипт в  chrome с автоматическим обновлением и выбором последовательно этих двух кликов ?

Comment: да, конечно, можно.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону инстурментов браузерного тестирования, например Selenium и его производные. Разобраться там не сложно, если хоть немного знаете логику HTML страниц и программирования, то будет легко

Можно конечно и через скрипт в chrome это сделать, но это возможно чуть сложнее